# Fastest way to read int starting from bit 3?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read a number, 23 bits in size. The number starts from the 3rd bit of the 1st byte.

```
unsigned char c*;//byte array
unsigned int start_byte = 0;//the byte to start reading from
unsigned int start_bit = 2;//start reading from the 3rd bit
unsigned int length_in_bits = 23;//read a number of size 23 bits
unsigned int number;//store the number here
```

I can do the above with many right and left shifts, in a loop.
**Question:** what's the **fastest** way to get a 23 bit number, starting from the 3rd bit of 1st byte?

When I say 3rd bit I mean: **00x00000**. The number is stored in the Big Endian format.

**NOTE:** When I say 23 bit number, 3rd bit, those are variables. The number will be anything from 1 bit to 32, the starting bit anything from 0-7.

Comment: look for a **way that works** first, then you will eventually find **faster** ways to do it. only looking for the **fastest** way will not get you anywhere fast :)

Comment: thanks, you have a point, but I need this function to run many times and I must make it pretty fast...

Comment: well, what is the third bit in your example? the third most or the third least significant bit? maybe a more concrete example would help.

Comment: Big endian or little endian?

Comment: The C and C++ standards do not specify performance characteristics of C and C++ implementations, except for computational complexity bounds on some library routines and, perhaps, incidental characteristics that are not significant to this problem. Therefore, there is no such thing as a “fastest way” in C or C++, any more than there is a “most purple way”; neither speed nor color is a property of the language. Finding fast ways to implement operations depends on specific C and C++ implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then let's give an answer with specific implementations in mind

Comment: @Kos: The number is stored in the Big Endian format.

Comment: right, it seems you just want to cut off the most significant 2 bits, and then shift the remainder to the right by sizeof(unsigned int) * 8 - 23 - 3 bits or something like that. you should be able to do that with an **&** and a **>>**

Comment: @Kos: Then the question should be closed as too broad, as there are too many C and C++ implementations to answer for, particularly since each processor model has different performance characteristics and therefore counts as a different implementation.

Comment: Okay, If you don't know the THE fastest way just tell me one of the fastest out there. @Andreas Grapentin: thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @Luka: What processor(s) are you targeting? Do you really need it to be **fastest**? How many times is the “many times” that this operation will be executed (per some unit of time)? Do you anticipate it will be a significant portion of the entire workload?

Comment: Intel x64 i7, ivy bridge. I will use this in a compression algorithm. This algorithm will be used a lot.

Comment: @Luka have you profiled the application to make sure this operation is actually a bottleneck? (If not this entire discussion is useless).

Comment: Most of the compression code is this function. I call this function a lot. The speed of the application is 5 times slower than I want it to be, so I am trying to make everything faster.

Comment: @Luka Borgleader has a point. You should try profiling your application to see where it actually spends most of its time, instead of guessing. have a look at gprof, or valgind, or graprof. those can find out where your program has bottlenecks.

Comment: I just put a timer before this and see the timer it takes.

Comment: @Luka **use a profiler.** timers are not profilers, they are never right, almost always misleading and not sufficient as an argument here.

Comment: You are right about a profiler, but as I said, I use this function too much. I use it maybe more than the multiplication operator

Comment: You did time this in Release configuration right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that does the bit-shifting for variable offsets and field widths. It is assumed that `skip` is in the range 0 to 7 and that `size` is in the range of 1 to 32. `size + skip` could be more than 32, in which case 5 bytes are accessed. This routine does not record the position of the byte pointer after reading, which could be anything from `c + 1` to `c + 5`.

```
uint32_t read_bits(const uint8_t *c, int skip, int size)
{
    uint8_t m = (1 << (8 - skip)) - 1;
    uint32_t u;

    u = *c++ & m;
    size -= (8 - skip);

    while (size > 0) {
        u = u << 8 | *c++;
        size -= 8;
    }

    u >>= -size;
    return u;
}
```

I've run only some cursory tests, but it looks okay. It probably also isn't the fastest way. Instead of calculating `m` with a bit shift, you could look up the values in a table:

```
static const uint8_t mask[] = {
    0xff, 0x7f, 0x3f, 0x1f, 0x0f, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01
};
uint8_t m = mask[skip];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitfields.

```
struct Helper
{
unsigned int throwAway : 2;
unsigned int number :23;
};
```

Then in code:

```
Helper* helperPtr = reinterpret_cast<Helper*>(c);
for(int i=0;i<NUM_INTEGERS;++i)
   std::cout << helperPtr[i].number <<" "; //integer #i
```

For reference, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx